# Add windows media player support in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a c# form application with windows player support. After a while I got the following two problems:

> 1. The designer cannot process unknown name 'axWindowsMediaPlayer1' at line  34.  The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.   Form1.Designer.cs   35  0
>
> 2.The type or namespace name 'AxWMPLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea why those error are risen? Where the AxWMPLib is located in order to add it in my project?

**EDIT:** I am trying to remove and re-add windows media player from menu&toolbars choose item COM, however I am receiving the following message:

> The following controls were successfully added to the the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET framework version.

Comment: I guess it is not an embeddable control.

Comment: How can I add AxWMPLib again?

Comment: User add reference, select COM, find Windows Media Player, and add it to the project. Did you tried this?

Comment: Yea I have already it add it.